# Exhaustively comparing all elements in nested each/map ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I wrote out a method that takes a collection rails params and existing model associations that have a column that I'm checking against for a value. What I've been doing so far is cleaning up the rails parameters and then iterating over the elements with the map for the nested loop array inside of it. The problem with this approach is that it sometimes misses values from either array. Its essentially not comparing every combination of both arrays. How do I compare every element combination in both arrays?

```
water_bottles = water_bottle_params.to_unsafe_h.map {|_w, v| v}

formatted_water_bottles = water_bottles.reject(&:blank?)
    
all_water_bottles = current_user.water_bottles
    
    formatted_water_bottles.each do |w|
    
      all_water_bottles.map |wb|
      
       if wb.name == w['name']
          raise "Water Bottle Exist!"
       end 
      end 
    end
```

Comment: without seeing the input data, it's hard to know what the problem could be. But I can say that `all_water_bottles.map...` should probably be `all_water_bottles.each ...`. Since you're just testing the elements for equality, and you're not using the returned map result.

Comment: you need to to check in both directions -- ie you need two sets of loops -- add another set with all_water_bottles as the outer and formatted_water_bottles as the inner

Comment: sounds good -- I'll try the multiloop approach

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want to raise an exception if any of the water bottle names from the `params` already exists in the database. If that is the case, the whole method can probably be written much simpler like this.

```
bottle_names = water_bottle_params.values.compact_blank
raise 'Water Bottle Exist!' if current_user.water_bottles.exists?(name: bottle_names)
```

This version uses a [`FinderMethods#exists?`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-exists-3F) to determine directly in the database if a matching bottle name exists. This is usually much faster than loading all records into memory and using array methods to compare both arrays. Additionally, this method requires less memory.

Other methods that I used to simplify the code: [`values`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-values) instead of `map { |_k, v| v }` and [`compact_blank`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-compact_blank) instead of `.reject(&:blank?)`.